# dhtmlxCalendar in dhtmlxWindow zIndex

Tags: calendar, window, dhtmlx

I attach a page with dhtmlxCalendar in dhtmlxWindow. And calendar is cut.
Main page:

```
dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
popupWindow = dhxWins.createWindow("newcontact_win", 0, 0, 330, 270);
popupWindow.center();
popupWindow.attachURL("calendar.html");
Attached page:
formData = [{type: "calendar",  dateFormat: "%d-%M-%Y", serverDateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d", name: "start_date", label: "Calendar", readonly: true, calendarPosition: "right"}];
myForm = new dhtmlXForm("myForm", formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calendar renders within the most nested iframe, which has smaller dimension than calendar. Physically impossible to draw calendar inside such small area. 
To get calendar visible normally  you need to build your code without using iframes (i.e. without using attachURL), then it must rendered good.